# Resource do JAX-RS como Session Bean ou CDI Managed Bean?

Tags: java, java-ee, ejb, cdi

Hoje esbarrei em um problema interessante ao tentar injetar um EJB em um recurso JAX-RS (no GlassFish 4.1, rodando a versão pré-instalada do Jersey).

```
@Stateless
public class MeuEJB implements MinhaInterface {
   // código
}

@Path("caminho")
public class MeuRecurso {
    @Inject
    private MinhaInterface minhaInterface;   
   // código
}
```

Ao tentar acessar o recurso recebia um `500 Internal Server Error` dizendo que não haviam candidatos válidos para injeção da `MinhaInterface`.

---

Tentando me aprofundar no assunto [descobri](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/ioc.html) que desde a versão 2.0 do Jersey ele inclui uma biblioteca de IoC chamada [HK2](https://hk2.java.net). Esse container aparentemente não conhece nada a priori sobre os escopos nem do CDI nem do EJB.

Uma alternativa óbvia é fazer o lookup jndi manualmente. Além disso existem soluções com [`InjectionManager`](http://blog.yonatan.me/2013/05/jersey-rest-jax-rs-glassfish-ejb-success.html) e com SPI.

Dito isso, o próprio [tutorial do Java EE 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jaxrs-advanced004.htm) dá duas receitas para integrar JAX-RS com EJB.

1. Transformar o recurso em um EJB:

   ```
   @Path("caminho")
   @Stateless
   public class MeuRecurso {
       @EJB
       private MinhaInterface minhaInterface;   
       // código
   }
   ```
2. Transformar o recurso em um bean do CDI:

   ```
   @Path("caminho")
   @RequestScoped
   public class MeuRecurso {
       @Inject
       private MinhaInterface minhaInterface;   
       // código
   }
   ```

Ambas as alternativas funcionam corretamente. O que eu gostaria de saber do ponto de vista arquitetural (e prático) é: Quais as implicações de transformar meu recurso JAX-RS em um *Stateless Session Bean* ou em um *CDI Managed Bean*? Já foram definidas melhores práticas nessa frente?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existem sim algumas diferenças entre utilizar um endpoint JAX-RS como um CDI bean / Stateless bean ou não utilizar nenhum dessas duas. Do ponto de vista prático, eu não vejo muita diferenciação entre qual usar, CDI ou EJB, a não ser as já conhecidas [**diferenças entre eles**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684112/how-do-cdi-and-ejb-compare-interact).

Abaixo seguem dois pontos práticos que são os mais importantes:

1. Propagação de transação: Tanto com o [@TransactionAttribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttribute.html) (EJB) ou [@Transactional](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/Transactional.html)(CDI) dão a possibilidade encapsular a transação e definir se ela será propagado aos "níveis / camadas / dependencia ou seja lá oque for" menores, por exemplo você pode definir que um único request será inteiramente envolvido em uma unidade transacional.
2. Recursos de segurança do JAAS (somente EJB) direto em seus recursos, com @RolesAllowed você pode definir seu esquema básico de segurança sem nenhum trabalho adicional.
3. Injeção de dependência: Aqui é a mesma coisa para os dois, como você mesmo já viu.
4. Acesso direto ao EntityManager (e qualquer outro recurso, JMS, JCA etc): Em casos de CRUD simples, não vejo o porque inchar o código e utilizar um pattern de 3 camadas(etc) para isso, neste ponto prático, utilizar um `em.merge(...)` diretamente em sua classe JAX-RS, simplifica muito a vida.

Em resumo, a questão de se ter um JAX-RS com EJB ou JAX-RS com CDI não muda em nada a não ser que você tenha que utilizar alguns dos recursos específicos dessas duas APIs. No caso de ciclo de vida das instâncias entre utilizar ou não, vejo que é a praticamente a mesma coisa já que os endpoints jaxrs já são gerenciados pelo container.

Vá de CDI até que você precise usar alguma feature específica do EJB. Apesar de hoje em dia não ter uma diferença grande de performance.(**[REF](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hp0rmEoe1xc)**).

Answer (score 1):

Não existe essa necessidade, a especificação do JAX-RS já define que o ciclo de vida de um resource é por request. Não faz sentido marcá-lo como @Stateless, por padrão ele não tem estado.

Acho que ainda não definiram um boa prática para isso. Eu uso CDI com @Inject, já é suficiente para minhas necessidades dentro de um resource.